# how can I avoid arrayof in xml conversion using xmlserialiser in c#?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

How can I avoid 'arrayof' in xml conversion using XmlSerializerin c#?
I have List of property class devices. List. I tried to convert the list as xml using XmlSerializer. I got the root element as ArrayofDevices. But I want only Device.

```
<ArrayOfDevice xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Comment: Can you improve your question by adding code samples for illustrating your problem?